# Discord.py chain subcommands

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a command `vote` that would accept 2 subcommands `start` or `end`.  The idea would be that if one isn't specified, it would use a default value I can set.  Otherwise it parses it using the functions `start` and `end`.

So for example, doing `$vote new start 5m` would use the default end time, and parse the start time.

Doing `$vote new end 5m` would use the default start time and parse the end time.

Doing `$vote new start 5m end 10m` would parse both the start and end time.

```
@vote.group(pass_context=True, invoke_without_command=True)
async def new(ctx):
    log.debug('New')
    # Do logic for default values here


@new.command()
async def start(ctx, start_time):
    # Parse start time
    delta = convert_to_timedelta(start_time)
    vote_date = datetime.today() + delta

@new.command()
async def end(ctx, end_time):
    # Parse end time
    delta = convert_to_timedelta(end_time)
```

But is there a proper way to chain this?  My current solution only used 1 command, `new`, and I parsed the arguments with something like `if 'start' in args`.

Would that be the best way to do it, or is there a more proper way to chain optional subcommands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below assumes that `convert_to_timedelta` will raise some kind of exception if it fails.  Here we define two converter classes that determine whether a word is start and end respectively. Using these, we can fit all of the logic into a single command:

```
from discord.ext.commands import Converter, BadArgument
from typing import Optional

class IsStart(Converter):
    async def convert(self, ctx, argument):
        if argument.lower() == 'start':
            return argument
        raise BadArgument(argument)

class IsEnd(Converter):
    async def convert(self, ctx, argument):
        if argument.lower() == 'end':
            return argument
        raise BadArgument(argument)

@bot.command()
async def comm(ctx, start: Optional[IsStart], starttime: Optional[convert_to_timedelta], 
                    end: Optional[IsEnd], endtime: Optional[convert_to_timedelta]):
    print(start, starttime, end, endtime)
    starttime = starttime if start else 'default_start'
    endtime = endtime if end else 'default_end'
    await ctx.send(f'{starttime} {endtime}')
```